# tellraw command with selector command doesnt' work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone help me by adding a selector into this command? I want `@p[score_quits_min=1]` to be added into this:

```
/execute @a[score_quits_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a [{"text":"WELCOME", "color":"gold"} *added right here* {"text":"TO THE REALM", "color":"gold"}]
```

I have the command connected to a clock and another command block with this command connected into the `/execute` command:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_quits_min=1] quits 0
```

I have been searching for an answer for a long time but never found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selector` string holds a selector to be parsed. It is exclusive with the the `text`, `translate`, and `score` tags, so it must not be mixed with them. Small example:

```
/tellraw @a ["Closest player to command block: ",{"selector":"@p"}]
```

Inserting into your command:

```
/execute @a[score_quits_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a [{"text":"WELCOME", "color":"gold"},{"selector":"@p[score_quits_min=1]"},{"text":"TO THE REALM", "color":"gold"}]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked out perfectly, i was going to ask how do i add color to it but I figured it out.